# C# - Get error result by sending images via NetworkStream

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I currently need to send big data (such as images) from a client(C#) to a server (C#). There is no problem with sending and receiving the string data via NetworkStream. But when sending large data (images) will get an error result (loss data or image crash). Any idea?

| client image output before sending (test_send.jpg) | output after the server received(test_received.jpg) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Server

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Port = 20000;
    TcpListener? server = null;
    try
    {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        server.Start();

        var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        
        // get image
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        int total = 0;
        int read = -1;
        do
        {
            if (!stream.CanRead)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("get");
            byte[] data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            read = stream.Read(data, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            total += read;
        } while (read > 0);

        Console.WriteLine("get image finish");
        Console.WriteLine($"total is {total}"); // 8590651
        
        byte[] image = ms.ToArray();

        // image.Length is different every time, I don't know why
        Console.WriteLine($"the byte array size is {image.Length}");

        File.WriteAllBytes("/Users/tim/Downloads/test_received.jpg", image);
        Console.WriteLine("saved");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        server?.Stop();
    }
}
```

Client

```
private static void SendData(byte[] image)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"image byte size is {image.Length}"); // 8590651
    File.WriteAllBytes("/Users/tim/Downloads/test_send.jpg", image); // test
    
    // TCP
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    try
    {

        tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 20000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"TCP connect error, {e.Message}");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        
        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
            stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"send error, {e.Message}");
    }

    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

Comment: TCP is a reliable connection, which means a 100% probability, the data received is the same as the original (sent by the client). I think the main problem is how you decode the received data. and decoding algorithm.

Comment: `ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);` should be `ms.Write(data, 0, read);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line

```cs
ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

It should be

```cs
ms.Write(data, 0, read);
```

---

To be honest, it's far easier to just use `CopyTo`.

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(ms);
```

---

You should also consider transitioning to a fully `async` flow, and you are also missing `using` everywhere.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int Port = 20000;
    TcpListener? server = null;
    try
    {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        server.Start();

        using var client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        using var stream = client.GetStream();
        
        // get image
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);

        Console.WriteLine("get image finish");
        Console.WriteLine($"total is {total}"); // 8590651
        
        byte[] image = ms.ToArray();

        // image.Length is different every time, I don't know why
        Console.WriteLine($"the byte array size is {image.Length}");

        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("/Users/tim/Downloads/test_received.jpg", image);
        Console.WriteLine("saved");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        if(server?.Active)
            server?.Stop();
    }
}
```

```cs
private static async Task SendData(byte[] image)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"image byte size is {image.Length}"); // 8590651
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("/Users/tim/Downloads/test_send.jpg", image); // test
    
    // TCP
    using var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    try
    {
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 20000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"TCP connect error, {e.Message}");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        using var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(image, 0, image.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"send error, {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

Consider also passing the `NetworkStream` directly to a `FileStream`.

Comment: Thank you. Any keywords or links for reference on passing the NetworkStream to a FileStream? Thanks again.

Comment: Not really, just the usual `await stream.CopyToAsync(yourFileStream);`